# Preserving some data on rollback in InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, transaction, percona

I want to keep log of attempted, sucessful, and failed operations (both for troubleshooting, and also for detecting malicious users trying things). I want to keep that log in InnoDB MySQL table.

Now, I also want to use transactions for access to all the other tables. So there arises the problem - if I rollback the transaction (or transaction do it by itself due to deadlock or whatever), my `INSERT INTO log_table` logs are also lost on rollback, which is a big problem.

I used to work around this by using `MyISAM` table for `log_table` which worked pretty good (as MyISAM doesn't support transactions, INSERTs into it were immediate, and were not undone on transaction rollback). However, `MyISAM` tables are on the way out in new versions, and are not really working all that good in cluster/replication/hotbackup environment which I want to pursue, so I am looking for another solution.

Only one I've found is using two concurrent connections to the MySQL server (one for `INSERT INTO log_table` with `autocommit=1`, and another one for running all the other stuff in `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` transactions). However that solution is problematic due to having a high number of connections (and per-connection resource usage) already.

Any other ways to preserve such log across rollbacks?

Note: I do not want to spool logs locally on the client running the application if at all possible (due to multitude of reasons; including clients low or nonexistant resources [thin client-alike], flaky connections [I want to know at which point big transactions die] and problematic low-tech users [who WILL try to kill clients mid-run if they can do it undetected]. While some of that issues can be worked around, that is a lot of extra work).

Comment: Will audit plugins satisfy the things you use `log_table` for?

Comment: You have presented a good description of the two methods I can think of.  (Suggest you refactor this Question to just ask the question, then write your own answer with the discussion of MyISAM and 2 connections.  If no one comes along with something better, "accept" your own answer.)

Comment: @danblack Thanks for pointer - but looking at the [audit plugin docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-audit-plugin-log-settings/) I don't think so - it looks to me it's just like [general query log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/general-query-log/) but which can be somewhat filtered and stored in InnoDB table instead of text file. Tring to parse, match and extract useful data from that would be a nightmare, storage requirements would be enormous (as I'd need to log all queries to get what I want), and I'd miss other context anyway (like content of other tables at that moment etc)